# What heap structure does C++ STL priority queue use?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, heap, priority-queue

Specifically, what heap variant does the STL priority queue container adaptor use? I'm benchmarking it vs my own hand rolled binary heap and double bucket structure implementations, so just wondering.  Bonus points for any interesting implementation knowledge!

Comment: The `std::*_heap` functions are a possibility.

Comment: Since this is implementation-specific, which particular implementation are you interested in?

Comment: On Visual Studio 2012, they use [std::make_heap()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) to create the heap. This is a max heap by default. You should just check the source code on your system if you want the exact details.

Comment: Implementation = Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

Comment: @chris: More than a possibility. `priority_queue` is specified to use those functions.

Answer (score 9):

This question is tagged C++ (as opposed to asking for implementation-specific details on a particular compiler), so I've checked the standard for any information. In various sections of 23.6.4 we learn that the `priority_queue` simply behaves as-if it uses `make_heap`, `push_heap`, and `pop_heap`. Then these functions are documented (in `25.4.6` sections) as having complexity `At most 3 * (last - first) comparisons.`, `At most log(last - first) comparisons.`, and `At most 2 * log(last - first) comparisons.` respectively. So certain heap implementations may be indicated by these characteristics, but no specific heap is called out.

Answer (score -2):

You can choose the container underlying the priority_queue. If not specified the default is to use a std::vector:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

> Container -   The type of the underlying container to use to store the
>   elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of
>   SequenceContainer. Additionally, it must provide the following
>   functions with the usual semantics: front() push_back() pop_back() The
>   standard containers std::vector and std::deque satisfy these
>   requirements.

The heap is implemented by the `*_heap` functions, in a straightforward way. You can inspect the code here:
 http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_heap.h

Comment: The choice of underlying container has nothing to do with how the heap is organized.